# My Perl script doesn't upload the files send from android device

Tags: java, android, perl

I try to upload file  from android app to a server using perl script  and it never works.

The perl script works perfectly if I upload from a html form from a browser but never from a app.
Appreciated any advice.

Please find below the perl script and the java class.

Perl Script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
use File::Basename;

$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000 * 5000;

my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";

my $upload_dir = "$ENV{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/android/videos";

my $query = new CGI;

my $filename = $query->param("upload_file");
#my $param2 = $query->param("param2");
#my $param3 = $query->param("param3");



if (!$filename) {
print $query->header ( );
print "ERROR MSG 123";
exit;
}

#prowerka za filename
my ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ( $filename, '..*' );
$filename = $name . $extension;
$filename =~ tr/ /_/;
$filename =~ s/[^$safe_filename_characters]//g;
if ( $filename =~ /^([$safe_filename_characters]+)$/ ) {
$filename = $1;
} else {
die "Filename contains invalid characters";
}


my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("upload_file");

if (!$upload_filehandle)
{
    die "Configuration file could not be loaded";
}
print $query->header;
open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";
binmode UPLOADFILE;

while ( <$upload_filehandle> )
{
    print UPLOADFILE;
}

close UPLOADFILE;
```

The Java class:

```
package com.androidexample.uploadtoserver;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

    TextView messageText;
    Button uploadButton;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    String upLoadServerUri = null;

    /**********  File Path *************/
    final String uploadFilePath = "/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100ANDRO/";
    final String uploadFileName = "DSC_0003.jpg";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

        messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- '/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100ANDRO/"+uploadFileName+"'");

        /************* Php script path ****************/
        upLoadServerUri = "http://www.suntrainer.com/cgi-bin/temp/upload.pl";

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                    }
                                });                      

                             uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                        }
                      }).start();        
                }
            });
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                                   +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("upload_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload_file\";filename=\""
                                             + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                String msg = "File Upload Completed. \n\n";

                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                                   + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 

           } // End else block 
         } 
}
```

Comment: Any errors either at the client or the server end?

Comment: No errors, in the Eclipse LogCat I get server response 200 OK .?!

Comment: What messages do you see on the web server that has the perl code? Also, what was the total "bytesRead" in the java code?

Comment: at the end  bytesRead is 0 , and I can not see messages on the server

Comment: Since you said the script works when using a web browser and java code is showing total "bytesRead" is zero, problem very likely is in the java code. What is the value of bufferSize?

Comment: 04-07 17:18:46.681: I/System.out(31979): bufferSize 0

Comment: what's the value of sourceFile.length()? I do think the call to Math.min inside the while loop should be: bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, bufferSize); You could overflow the buffer array otherwise.

Comment: 04-07 18:10:38.942: I/System.out(2592): sourceFile.length() 1612189
This java code is exact copy of upload demo app http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106   . I was expecting to work on 100% ?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Before you first call to set bytesAvailable, you should read in some data from the filestream:

```
       // read file and write it into form...
       bufferSize = maxBufferSize;
       buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
       bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

       // create a buffer of  maximum size
       bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
```

Your filestream does not have any data in it, so you end up with a buffer size of 0 and never get to read in any data.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple and general:
1. Import httpmime-4.1 into your "libs" and add it to the build path

1. Import those:

   import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
   import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
   import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
   import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
   import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
   import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
   import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody;
   import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
   import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
   import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
   import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
2. Example method below:

   public void uploadMime() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

   ```
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(upLoadServerUri);
   File file = new File(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

   MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
   ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file);
   mpEntity.addPart("upload_file", cbFile);
   StringBody contentString = new StringBody("me_again");
   mpEntity.addPart("new_file_name",contentString);

   httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
   System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
   HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

   System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
   if (resEntity != null) {
   System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
   }
   ```

   }

That's it. Thanks for the advices.